# HttpWebRequest not posting

Tags: c#, web-services

As per the question, I `POST` json to http but I'm not getting any output when I use `GET`.

I'm trying to `POST` json then close the stream. I do not need to care about the reply. To check if my `POST` is working, I've written`GET`.

Below is my code for `POST`.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1234/xxxxx/xxxx");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{   
    string eventData = "temp string";
    string jsonEvent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
    streamWriter.Write(jsonEvent);
}

var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); //getting "The remote server returned an error:" here
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Below is my code for `GET` which I got from msdn.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1234/xxxxx/xxxx");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never asking for a response, so it's not making the request. Just add:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Use the response
}
```

Note that your "get" code isn't exception-safe - it should use `using` statements instead of calling `Close` explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean I'll need to add reponse in `POST`?

Comment: @active92: I don't know what you mean - your code is the *client* code. It's not up to you to add a response. But until you call `GetRespose()` it isn't going to make a request. It's fine for the server to return an empty response body.

Comment: I've added the response code but it is giving me an error `The remote server returned an error:`

Comment: @active92: Well that potentially means you've provided an invalid request... that's a different matter. Research it, then post a new question if necessary. (You should look at the exact response - it may well contain information.)